# Office 365 - How to create OutlookServiceClient?

Tags: api, office365

I need to integrate Office 365 Calendar in my application. I've already installed the Extensions and Office Tools. And have the Library references

using Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices;
using Microsoft.Office365.Discovery;

And try to create OutlookServiceClient in Web Forms application.

But it fails, Please suggest me what to do ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How does it fail? Did you use the "Add Connected Service" menu to add the Calendar service?

Comment: Yes i add the calendar permission From add connected Service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-calendar-tasks-client-library 
It's described pretty clear how to get OutlookServiceClient